# Produce a specific exception in python

Tags: python, exception, boto3

I'd like to produce an exception specific to the error that I'm getting.

On obtaining a session for AWS the user must input an MFA code:

```
try:
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account,region_name='us-east-1')
except ValidationError as validation_error:
    print(f"A validation error has occurred: {vallidation_error}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An exception has occurred: {e}")
    set_regions(aws_account)
```

The exception looks like this:

```
An exception has occcurred: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the AssumeRole operation: 2 validation errors detected: Value '2121212dsa' at 'tokenCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\d]*; Value '2121212dsa' at 'tokenCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 6
```

Why does my line `except ValidationError as validation_error:` not work? How can I produce an exception that is unique to this error?

Comment: Do you want a custom error? Currently all you are doing is appending the strings A validation error has occurred in front of the actual error message which does nothing information wise.

Comment: Yes I would like a custom error.

Comment: If you make a custom error, `boto3.Session(...)` won’t know about it. You’ll probably have to use regex to find out the error name contained in `str(e)`.

Comment: python version?

Comment: I'm on version 3.8.

Comment: When I convert `e` to a string I get: `An exception has occcurred: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: MultiFactorAuthentication failed with invalid MFA one time pass code.` How do I get a custom error from that?

Comment: Try: `print(type(e))` (or other similar inspection techniques) in the final except clause to determine the exact exception to catch.

Comment: You have a typo in the call to print for validation error

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a typo in {vallidation_error} should be {validation_error} ?

I see this code running ok ( I tried with other exceptions, try uncommented one exception at a time below.

```py
try:
    #session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account,region_name='us-east-1')
    #raise ValueError("A validation error occurred while creation a session")
    raise NameError(" A name error exception ocurred")
except ValueError as validation_error:
    raise
    print(f"A validation error has occurred: {validation_error}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An exception has occurred: {e}")
    #set_regions(aws_account)
```

OUTPUT

When uncommented ValueError:

```sh
raise ValueError("A validation error occurred while creation a session")
ValueError: A validation error occurred while creation a session
```

When uncommented NameError(like the example):

```sh
An exception has occurred:  A name error exception occurred
```

I'm assuming you correctly imported the exception

Answer (score 0):

Check following points:

1. You have installed `botocore` library
2. Import the exceptions that will be used using `from botocore.exceptions import ValidationError`

The code sould look like:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ValidationError

...

try:
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account,region_name='us-east-1')
except ValidationError as validation_error:
    print(f"A validation error has occurred: {vallidation_error}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An exception has occurred: {e}")
    set_regions(aws_account)
```

PS: it seems you have not import the exceptions in the script.